# MKMapView userTrackingMode overridden by CLSqliteDatabaseManager

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, mapkit, core-location

I am setting the userTrackingMode of an MKMapView instance in my UIViewController's viewLoaded method. The first time the view loads I set it to MKUserTrackingModeFollowWithHeading successfully. However every subsequent time the view loads, though I again set its value to MKUserTrackingModeFollowWithHeading, this is almost immediately overritten by MKUserTrackingModeNone. I have subclassed MKMapView and overridden setUserTrackingMode, inserting a breakpoint so I can see where it is being called from. The same thing happens in both simulator and on device:

On simulator I get the following from the stack when the value is set to MKUserTrackingModeNone:

[image]

On my device (iPhone 4s) I get the following:

[image]

There is very little else going on in my application and certainly nothing that is directly triggering the property to be set. What is CLSqliteDatabaseManager? Google returns not a single result. On the device how on earth can MKMapRectContainsRect be involved? I'm using iOS 5.0.

Answer (score 2):

It seems too late to answer.  But it may still be helpful for whoever is looking for an answer.

I had exactly same problem.  Suddenly I figure out why.  Please load your iOS build-in Maps app and click the small arrow button at bottom-left corner to start tracking your location.  As soon as you drag the map.  The tracking is stopped.  Same reason, if you move the map in your code, the `MKMapView` property `userTrackingMode` will be reset to `MKUserTrackingModeNone` automatically.

In my case, I called `setCenterCoordinate` after set `userTrackingMode` to `MKUserTrackingModeFollow` in `- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated`.  It worked fine after moving around the code `mapView.userTrackingMode = MKUserTrackingModeFollow;` to the end.